# Is there a way to catch unknown struct fields?

Tags: dynamic, struct, rust, field

```
struct Test;

// here must be code to overload the standard field resolution methods

fn main() {
    let t = Test;
    println!("I wanna catch request for unknown struct field {}", t.unexpected_field)
}
```

Comment: It will be caught by the compiler.  Isn't it also the best case scenario that this is caught pre-execution?

Answer (score 5):

No. Rust is a statically compiled language; everything must be resolved at compile time. Either a field exists or it does not.

Even if the field did conditionally exist, you wouldn't know what type it was so you wouldn't know what methods exist on it. The compiler wouldn't know what size the field is so it couldn't allocate space for the structure to begin with.

It's more likely that you want to use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html):

```
struct Test {
    unexpected_field: Option<i32>,
}
```

Or you could switch to a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html).

---

Editorially, this is a *huge* reason to have a statically-compiled language and it's a great thing.

Comment: Even though having *dynamic* macrosses in the language, where `AST` is parsed at runtime, will be very useful too (building your own `DSL` language..etc) . At the end, we have `unsafe` (you can shoot yourself in the foot) , so I would expect introduction of dynamic artifacts be something in the future of this language.

Comment: @Tigran Macros are not parsed at runtime, they are parsed during compilation just like regular Rust code. Rust is a systems programming language and so I very much doubt dynamic anything (a la Ruby/Javascript/Python) is going to be introduced in the future.

Comment: @Tigran You are probably looking for a parser or a scripting language engine, not a core language feature. Luckily, crates.io has you served on these ends.